# escape URL quesrystring

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsurl

I make a request to an external API using GET method. 
For some reasons, the results which I get do not work if the searchText contains spaces e.g. it works fine for stackoverflow, but if searchText is entered as "stack overflow", it will not work (Assume both the values are present). Do I need to escape before making the URL request?

```
NSString *urlstr = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://mysite.com/xyz?nameBeginsWith=%@", searchText];
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Did you try this one?

```
NSString *urlstr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://mysite.com/xyz?nameBeginsWith=%@", searchText];
urlstr = [urlstr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

`stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` takes a string and returns the same string percent escaped to be legally used as a URL. So the answer to your question would be yes, `NSURL` needs a properly escaped string to be initialized

[NSURL Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Hey..that's fine..Thanks again for your help on this..U ROCK

Answer (score 1):

The method `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` is now deprecated.

The correct way to escape urls is:

> NSString * escapedSearchText = [searchText stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]];
>
> NSString * url = [NSString
>   stringWithFormat:@"http://example.com/xyz?nameBeginsWith=%@",
>   escapedSearchText];